# Hide Laravel API url access from public view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-10

I have a Laravel 10 project that has both the front end and the back end within the same project.

This website renders information from a database. Everything works as expected.

I have two route files
web.php and api.php

I have the following API route:
https://example.com/api/product/1

This is an example of the output from that route:

```
{"id":1,"name":"name","description":"hello world"}
```

I have other routes that return much more complex data.

I need access to the API routes from inside my application. I have some internal react components that use axios to retrieve the data. This part works fine.

What I am trying to do is to "secure" the API route so that it cannot be accessed from outside my Laravel application. Therefore, if the request is coming from my blade views or my react app then the server will return the data. However, if someone types the API address on the browser I want it to throw an error (not authorized).

Update: I am using Laravel Sanctum for auth, however, I am not looking to make API requests accessible to users with an authorized token.

I want the data to be controlled by the view, I don't want users to easily access the API, copy the data and take everything away with one click.

What is the best approach to designing such a system like this?

Comment: Google "Cross Site Request Forgery". I'm sure Laravel has something built-in that you can use to implement CSRF protection. Do note that if your application has no authentication at all (as in some sort of login), then there is nothing that stops anyone from mimicking what your frontend does. CSRF protection will slow someone down, but never stop them.

Comment: have you tried to use Laravel Sanctum in your project?

Comment: In order for your front-end application to send a request to your backend your code is downloaded by a client's browser and executed. It is the client that sends requests to your backend so it is the client that you need to authorise and not your application.

Comment: have you considered implementing apikey? so that your API won't be accessible without it?

Comment: Currently using Sanctum. Updated question. I am not looking to allow access to certain users, I would like an API route to be accessible only to my react components or blade view. Upon further research, it seems that what I am trying to accomplish is impossible. I will probably need to pass the data directly to the blade view if I really want to hide the "raw" data object returned from an API.

Comment: I have the same "problem". Have you reached any solution?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you basically created a public API.
Your frontend code relies on this API.
There are only a few options which will help you in this case:

1. You use Server-Side-Rendering so that you don't need to expose your API in the first place. This is by far the most useful way of not having other people call your API. You are still affected by scraping and this approach will cost some more computing power on the server.
2. Add a API-Key to this API endpoint which you then give out restrictively.
   For example every 24 hours you generate a new API key with the validity time of a bit more than 24 hours so it won't expire whilst users use your site.
   You then dynamically add this API key to your frontend code so it changes every 24 hours. (Keep in mind that as long your API is accessible via the public, people can and will find a way to still call and automate this API no matter how good you obfuscate it)
3. You use rate limits and pagination so you don't send all the data inside of your database to the user on every request. This however is heavily reliant on the use case.